# numpy.transpose for producing mirror images

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I am familiar with numpy.transpose command that it is used to swap axes. But I am not familiar with mirror images that what they are and how numpy.transpose command is used to generate mirror image. The following link says that when we swap last two axis we get mirror images. So what is meant by mirror images here. I will be really thankful if someone please explain this with some picture

```
`a= np.arange(2*2*4).reshape(2,2,4)
b= np.transpose(a,(1,0,2))`
```

please look https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8TdC.jpg

https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/734lcl/complicated_numpy_transpose_question/?st=jij0av7a&sh=754dfd45

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you're asking here. You aren't sure what `np.tranpose` is doing in this case?

Comment: Are you looking for `np.fliplr`?

Comment: I read some where if I transpose last two axis. np.transpose(a,(0,2,1)) you will get mirror image. I want to understand by applying this command what I am doing with the two images?

Comment: No I am not looking for np.fliplr. I am bound to use np.transpose

Comment: I am quiet familiar with np.transpose command. how by replacing last two axis I can get mirror image?What I am doing with the two samples(images). How to imagine this

Comment: If you are trying to mirror an image, you shouldn't be using `np.transpose`. You can use `np.fliplr` to create a horizontal mirror, or `np.flipud` for a vertical mirror. These are equivalent to  `arr[..., :-1]` and `arr[::-1, ...]` respectively. It is still unclear to me what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [54]: a= np.arange(2*3*4).reshape(3,2,4)
#                                    | | |
# axes                               0 1 2

# new shape by moving the axes
In [54]: b= np.transpose(a,(1,0,2))

In [55]: a.shape
Out[55]: (3, 2, 4)

# first two axes are swapped
In [56]: b.shape
Out[56]: (2, 3, 4)
```

By default, `np.transpose()` reverses the shape. But, when passing an argument to `np.transpose()` the array is reshaped to the requested shape if possible.

---

Explanation:

In the above example, `np.transpose(a, (1, 0, 2))` means that in the returned array `b`, the zeroth and first axes would be swapped.

Specifically, the tuple that's passed to `np.transpose()` is the order in which we want our resultant array to have the shape.

---

Plotting the image before (left) and after transposing (right):

[image: transposed result]

Comment: I am familiar with swapping of axis. If I have to explain this in words how I will do that? Can I say that I am combining the first pixels of both images? And what about mirror images?How swapping last two axis gives mirror images

Comment: @python added a plot!

Comment: what about np.transpose(a, (0,2,1)). Can you please show this by plotting